# Disable dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having Two Dropdown name as Product and Product line and both are dependent on each other such that after selecting any product only Product Line dropdown will get enable. the sample structure is as below.

```
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select" disabled="">
<option value="">All products</option>
<option value="AA">Product1</option>
<option value="BB">Product2</option>
<option value="BB">Product3</option>
</select>
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product-line" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select" disabled="">
<option value="">All products Line</option>
<option value="CC">ProductLine1</option>
<option value="DD">ProductLine2</option>
<option value="EE">ProductLine3</option>
</select>

<SCRIPT>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  
  checkDropdownvalue();
});

function disableProductline() { 
    document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product-line"]').disabled = true;
}

function checkDropdownvalue() {
  document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product"]').onchange = (e) => {
    var selectedProductline = e.target.value;
    alert(e.target.value) 
                
    if (selectedProductline == "AA") {
      disableProductline();
    }   
  }
}

</SCRIPT>
```

on select of AA in product dropdown ill needed to disable the ProductLine Dropdown.

But i'm guessing due to some razor view changes Product Line dropdown is keep getting enable as the data in Product Line is dynamically inserted

So is there any way such that my code will execute at the end to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in My case Product Line dropdown was getting enable due to some razor view code. In order resolve this instead of comparing value of a product on change of product dropdown I have done the comparison on Product Line dropdown like if i hover my mouse over Product line dropdown it then trigger an event to check the selected product and compare it with the one i want (i have not used onClick as momentarily(for few milisec) it open the dropdown and then disable it  ) i have used below JS script to achieve this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() 
{  
document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product-line"]').onmouseover = function fun() {
       
        var selectedproduct =  getSelectedProduct();
        /* alert(selectedproduct.value); */
        if(selectedproduct.value == "AA")
        {
            document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product-line"]').disabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product-line"]').disabled = false;
        }  
           
         
    }
  
});

function getSelectedProduct(){
var sel = document.querySelector('select[name="abb_sf_partners-product"]');

 var selectedP =  getSelectedOption(sel);
 
 function getSelectedOption(sel) {
        var opt;
        for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            opt = sel.options[i];
            if ( opt.selected === true ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return opt;
    }
return selectedP    
}
```

I hope it will help someone lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  checkDropdownvalue();
});

function checkDropdownvalue() {
  const productSelect = document.querySelector('[name="abb_sf_partners-product"]');
  const productLine = document.querySelector('[name="abb_sf_partners-product-line"]')
  productSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value === 'AA') {
      productLine.disabled = true;
    } else {
      productLine.disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select">
  <option value="">All products</option>
  <option value="AA">Product1</option>
  <option value="BB">Product2</option>
  <option value="BB">Product3</option>
</select>
<select name="abb_sf_partners-product-line" data-abb-sf-productelement="" class="abb-select" disabled="true">
  <option value="">All products Line</option>
  <option value="CC">ProductLine1</option>
  <option value="DD">ProductLine2</option>
  <option value="EE">ProductLine3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your provided code is correct but im using the similar approach on my current Javascript code.i was able to disable the dropdown but once the product line values are populated again its getting enable which is annoying me lol. thanks for your response